# Confusion of “Definitely not “

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Conversation as below
Friend said he doesn’t like looking at pictures or videos of himself
So I commented
“ maybe my edit ( I made a video of him diving ) isn’t Good enough !?

He replied , “ definitely not your edit”.

What does that mean ?
Does it mean it has nothing to do with my edit or he just doesn’t like Looking at pictures

Comment: I'd surmise that there's a gap here. "I don’t like looking at pictures or videos of myself  ...  [and] definitely not your edit.”

Comment: I think it would depend on tone of voice and emphasis: emphasizing "your" would be different to emphasizing "definitely"/"not".

Comment: @StuartF has it right. When information is left out, it's ... left out. The phrase _definitely not your edit_ could be short for _(and it's) definitely not your edit (that I object to)_, **or** it could be short for what Edwin Ashworth suggests in his comment above. Intonation and facial expression would distinguish easily. But not in print.

Comment: Why do people come here to ask what their friends meant, when they could just ask them?